# Drop Down menu issues (2) - HTML5 & CSS

Tags: css, html, drop-down-menu, css-sprites, navigationbar

I am brand new at coding and am working on the final project for my class. It's like web page 101: the very basics in HTML5 and a little CSS. The demos we built for class look like they're from the 90s. Simple is fine, but I really want to challenge myself so I am attempting something more complicated.

TL;DR I have zero skills and my code is probably messy, please bear with me!

I ran into some trouble with the navigation menu I'm making. Maybe one of you can help me out :)

When I mouse over each item in the textured metal bar, blood splatter/paint/ketchup shows up. "CONTENTS" has a drop down menu that changes color when hovering over a list item in it.

But...

1) The text links are gone. I don't know what happened to them, but I do know that they had vanished BEFORE I added the Multiply opacity to the background-color. I think maybe it was after I had the BG color change on hover. I need the links to be solid white.

2) Is there any way to have "CONTENTS" show as red-splattered while I am hovering over the drop down list items? (as opposed to only when I am hovering over "CONTENTS" itself?)

Here is my code, and here is the sprite image

[image]

in case you need it.

EDIT: Here is the JSfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/dkxovdj1/

Thanks so much!

```
> ul#nav {
     margin:0 0 0 0; 
     padding:0; 
     list-style:none;
     clear: both;     
}

ul#nav ul.dd li a {text-decoration: none;
                   color: white;}



#nav li {

     text-indent:-9999px; 
     display:inline; 
     float:left; 
     width: 495px;
    position: relative;
}

#nav li a {
    background:url(navbar_main2.jpg) no-repeat; 
    width: 495px; 
    height: 101px; 
    display:block;
}


 #nav li.nav-1 {width:144px; height:154px;}
 #nav li.nav-1 a:hover{background-position:0px -101px;}
 #nav li.nav-1 a{background-position:0px 0px;}   

 #nav li.nav-2 {width:151px; height:154px;}  
 #nav li.nav-2 a:hover{background-position:-144px -101px;}
 #nav li.nav-2 a{background-position:-144px 0px;} 

 #nav li.nav-3 {width:308px; height:154px;}  
 #nav li.nav-3 a:hover{background-position:-295px -101px;} 
 #nav li.nav-3 a{background-position:-295px 0px;} 


#nav li ul.dd {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 101px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 175px;
    background-color: #524f4a;
    mix-blend-mode: multiply; 
    line-height: 25px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
    opacity: 0.7;
    text-align: center;


}
#nav li:hover ul.dd{
    display: block;
    }
}
#nav li ul.dd li{
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 px;
    text-indent: 0;
    width: 115px;
    height: 25px;

    }


#nav li ul.dd li a{
    top: 7px;
    background: none;
    display: block;
    width: 105px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-radius: 7px;
    margin: 2px;
}


#nav ul.dd li:hover a:hover {background-color: #ffde43;}

ul.dd li {position: absolute; right: 24px; top: 8px;}
```

Comment: Can you make a fully working example? Preferably as a snippet here in the question (edit the question and click the `<>` button), or on http://jsfiddle.net or http://codepen.io or http://jsbin.com or somewhere.

Comment: Ok I added the link in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the text not showing up is a typo.  You have the following in your fiddle:

```
#nav li:hover ul.dd {
    display: block;
    } /* <-- should not be here */
}
```

The hover state can be amended to be `#nav li.nav-1:hover a` instead of `#nav li.nav-1 a:hover`.  That should get the red to display when hovering over the submenu

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/w0hq3L06/

**Edit:**
Per [the comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33950431/drop-down-menu-issues-2-html5-css/33962697?noredirect=1#comment55683570_33962697),

```
background-color: #524f4a;
mix-blend-mode: multiply;
```

should be

```
background-color: rgba(82, 79, 74, 0.7);
background-blend-mode: multiply;
```

and the opacity on the `#nav li ul.dd` style should be dropped entirely.
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/w0hq3L06/2/

Comment: Also the space between the list items in the drop down disappeared

Comment: Oops I deleted my comment above by mistake. Text is being multiplied like the background color is, any way to make it solid white?

Comment: @JXO Not sure what you mean. Here's what I see: http://imgur.com/YsLDM4b.  It looks solid white to me.  What browser/OS are you using?

Comment: Won't show if the BG is white http://i232.photobucket.com/albums/ee1/jadex9980/Whatever/Screen%20Shot%202015-11-27%20at%201.47.34%20PM.jpg

Comment: @JXO it was easier to write it in the answer.  See my edit above.

Comment: Do keep in mind, however, that blend mode is not well supported.  And I mean at all: http://caniuse.com/#search=background-blend-mode

Comment: I see what you mean lol. I took the blend mode out, it was getting weird. What a shame, it was so nice! The nav bar is near perfect now. You are really good at this. The last issue is that I can't seem to get the li items to have space in between them like before.

Comment: @JXO Yeah, it is a shame.  We'll see it eventually.  Just takes a while for IE to catch up.  For the spacing, it's because the `#nav li ul.dd li` rule sets an explicit height of `25px`.  The problem is that the anchor within that list item also has a height of `25px` and a `2px` margin.  margin isn't counted toward the height, so you have 29px tall anchors (25 height + 2 top margin + 2 bottom margin), which are being forced into the 25px `li`.  Just remove the height from the `li` (which allows the anchor to determine the height) and it should work: http://jsfiddle.net/w0hq3L06/4/

Comment: Note that while your individual anchors are 29px tall, margins do "collapse", so the actual height of your anchors are roughly 27px if you include the margin.

Comment: Ohhh I understand now. The nav menu is perfect now. I can't thank you enough! If you ever need anything photoshopped or retouched just let me know <3